# Data reader in command using statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a legacy system that I have noticed the following code in

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
using(var connection = new SqlConnection())
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
     command.commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     //Attach command parameters etc. 
     var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
     dataTable.Load(reader);
}
return dataTable;
```

Normally I would wrap the data reader into a using statement so the lines would read:

```
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
   dataTable.Load(reader);
}
```

I think that I'll schedule the time in to update these methods to include a using statement for the data reader as well, but I was wondering whether anyone knew whether, in the instance above, the datareader will get disposed of when the command or connection is disposed of anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it yourself, since the command doesn't clear up the `DataReader` for you. See as an example [`SqlCommand.Dispose`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs).

It is save in this situation to use a `using` since `DataTable.Load` doesn't keep a reference to the `DataReader` used. As a proof of that, see the [reference source of `DataTable`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/DataTable.cs).

Comment: Okay - unfortunately that doesn't actually answer the question asked by the OP, namely whether the `DataReader` will already be disposed when the command/connection is disposed.

Comment: Yup. Admittedly it's hard to tell what the impact of not disposing of the reader will be, but that's slightly different anyway.